# Why is a linear transformation called linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

$T(av_1 + bv_2) = aT(v_1) + bT(v_2)$

Why is this called linear? $f(x) =ax + b$, the simplest linear equation does not satisfy $f(x_1 + x_2) = f(x_1) + f(x_2)$.

Thank you.

Comment: The term linear is not in reference to the equation of a line, as in a polynomial of degree one. Linearity means that both addition and scalar multiplication are preserved: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Sorry, but apparently all lines of interest pass through $0$.

Comment: @MPW : All (non-affine) linear subspaces of a vector space contain $0$.  The affine subspaces need not do so.

Comment: As I think $f=\text{constant}$ is the most simplest one.

Comment: Very good question. Thank you.

Answer (score 47):

Yep, in high school we say $f(x) = 3x + 4$ is a linear function, but as you point out, in linear algebra it's not. It's irritating.

The word for $x \mapsto ax + b$ is [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), and this is the term you'll hear elsewhere in higher math.

Answer (score 21):

https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2490/why-do-we-call-a-linear-mapping-linear-mapping

As [explained there](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/2492), the term *linear mapping* was coined by Hermann Graßmann. It describes mappings which preserve the *linear structure* of a space, meaning the way scaling the length of a vector parameterizes a *line*. If you apply a linear mapping, the image will still be a line.

Now, that's actually true for affine maps as well, so it could be argued that the high school term, using *linear* to mean functions of the form $\backslash x \mapsto a\cdot x + b$, is actually more meaningful. But alas, sometimes sub-optimal terminology sticks. There has by now been so much written about *linear maps* meaning functions that fulfill $f(\mu\cdot \mathbf v + \nu\cdot \mathbf w) = \mu\cdot f(\mathbf v) + \nu\cdot f (\mathbf w)$, that it would mostly cause confusion to use it for anything else.

Answer (score 19):

Expressions of the form $av_1 + bv_2$ are called linear combinations. Linear transformations are the functions sending linear combinations to linear combinations (preserving coefficients). That is, a function is called linear when it preserves linear combinations.

Comment: Are you kicking the can? why are those expressions called linear combinations?

Comment: It is pretty reasonable if you think about it visually: for a nonzero vector $v$, the set of all $av$ as $a$ varies is the *line* through $v$.  Thus for nonzero vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$, the set of all $av_1+bv_2$ as $a$ and $b$ vary is the set of all sums of elements from *two lines* and hence it's reasonable to call that a linear combination.  We let the terminology be used also if $v_1$ or $v_2$ is the zero vector since *this is convenient*.

Answer (score 3):

You may refer to them as "$k$-vectorspace homomorphisms" if you wish.

In a little more detail: if $k$ is a field, then a $k$-vectorspace can be thought of as a set $X$ equipped with, for each sequence $a \in k^n$, a corresponding "linear combination mapping" $X \leftarrow X^n$. By convention, the structure-preserving mappings between $k$-vectorspaces are called "$k$-linear transforms," or simply *$k$-linear*, probably because the phrase "linear-combination-mapping-preserving mapping" is altogether too confusing. Like I said, you may refer to them as $k$-vectorspace homomorphisms if you wish.

But this just pushes the issue back: why are they called, of all things, *linear* combinations? Well, if $X$ is a $k$-vectorspace we're given a single vector $x \in X$, then $$\{ax : a \in k\}$$ is the set of all elements of $X$ that can be obtained by applying linear combination mappings to $x.$ In the special case where $k=\mathbb{R}$, this can be visualized as a line through the origin.

So "linear combination" is probably best thought of as a shorthand for "line-through-the-origin combination." Of course, if we've got two vectors, then we're potentially talking about a plane through the origin. And so on.

In fact, linear algebra isn't really about lines at all; its really about flat things that pass through the origin. Perhaps it should have been called "algebra with respect to the origin" instead!

Answer (score 2):

Linearity has different (yet equivalent) definitions. One is what you described: preservation of linear combinations (linear combination of inputs yields linear combination of outputs), which is a godsend when solving equations - solve each part separately, and you have a general solution. In physics, this is called the principle of superposition. Secondly, it's linear in the sense of a linear function (meaning first powers in all terms). Linear functions, either in scalar context ($ax+b$) or in multiple variables (linear algebra, matricess and everything that goes with it) satisfy the superposition principle, when $b=0$. However, even when $b\neq 0$ (general affine transformations), you can work in homogeneous coordinates. Just introduce another variable that assumes a value of $1$ in your expression, and you see that the affine transform is linear (in the superposition sense) in a higher dimensional space, and projected down (the projection is in this case literal - in 3D graphics, $4\times 4$ matrices are used explicitly to render everything on your screen). Not every superposition preserves the affine transform, but linear *interpolations* do. This is the cornerstone of the formalism used to deal with differences between absolute and relative quantities (prominent in physics). Example: represent all *positions* as (x,y,z,1), and *displacements* as (x,y,z,0): in that case, it's obvious that a difference of positions is a displacement, an interpolation of positions is a position, position + scaled displacement = position, but scaling a position makes no sense (2*London = ?).

In short: offset of general affine transforms can be factored away into an extra dimension of homogeneous space, then all definitions of linearity make sense in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the equation is true in the trivial case, where b=0.

As others have pointed out, when b is not equal to zero, the result is called an [affine transformation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AffineTransformation.html).

By definition, an affine transformation does preserve the other underlying properties of the original linear function, because it is a "parallel" shift That's why it's considered a "linear" transformation, even though the term is, in fact, slightly misleading in this context.