# Linear Function: f(ax + by) = af(x) + bf(y) vs y = ax+b.

Tags: machine-learning

I studied a linear function definition in our Machine Learning course:

```
f(ax + by) = af(x) + bf(y)
```

Using this definition, we can prove that y = ax + b is NOT a linear function. This is counter-intuitive to me.

```
For example: f(x) = 2x + 3 is NOT linear.
f(0 + 1) = f(1) = 5
but f(0)+f(1) = 3+ 5 = 8. 
Hence f(0+ 1) != f(0)+f(1)
```

We all know that y =  ax + b is a line function (I know this is a linear function for ages), but it is not linear according to this definition. I am very confused.

In what situation we should use the above definition?

Recourse:

https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~idarcy/COURSES/34/linearfn2s.pdf

Comment: For better or for worse, linear functions need $f(0) = 0$, and the more general "linear" functions with $f(0)\neq 0$ are called affine. This is just notation, but I don't know how it came about. See answers here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623211/why-is-a-linear-transformation-called-linear

Comment: The short answer is that functions of the form $y=ax+b$ have their graphs in the form of a line, and so got their name.  In the context of vector spaces and linear algebra, etc..., the property that some functions have that $f(ax+by)=af(x)+bf(y)$ is incredibly useful and so a whole branch of mathematics was formed to study these examples more deeply.  We happened to give such functions the name "linear functions" despite the fact that this name (*or something like it*) was already in use for something different.  Sometimes words are reused in maths to mean different things (*e.g. Regular*).

Comment: Consider the comically large number of different uses of the word [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular#Mathematics) and [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal#Mathematics) in mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $y=ax+b$ is the composition of a linear function $y=ax$ with a translation $b$. Even if $y=ax+b$ is not linear it preserves some properties of the related linear function and it is denoted as an [affine function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space) and more precisely as an affine line in that case.

Answer (score 3):

linear function $\neq$ linear polynomial

The former is what you have defined in your Machine learning course.  The latter is functions like $ax+b$.  See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity) for more details and context.

Linear functions are very important in the subject of linear algebra.